# Overlay pop up box using jquery1.6.1..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I had a script for overlay popup box using jquery1.4.1 using modal, which returns some function in my page getting not working which are used by jquery1.6.1..

So, when I add jQuery 1.4.1 script for displaying pop up box.. the functions working through jQuery 1.6.1 got interrupted..

How can I get popup box using jQuery 1.6.1?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://simplemodal.googlecode.com/files/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function modalTest() {
    showModal();
    setTimeout(function() {
        hideModal();
    },2000000);
}

function showModal() {
    $("#downloadbox").modal();
}

function hideModal() {
    $.modal.close();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problems may be

1) Certain functions in jquery 1.4.1 have been deprecated in 1.6.1

One solutions is , please upgrade the plugin to newer version , it may solve your problem

Otherwise you need to edit the plugin to accommodate the new functions ,its risky

Answer (score 0):

jQuery latest is 1.7.1. Are you sure your page is loading 1.6.1? That's beside the point, though: what may be happening here is that your scripts are firing before the document is ready. No idea why it worked for 1.4.1 since that's so long ago (as duke mentions, deprecated functions?), but you should wrap this in a document ready function to see if it works:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

// your existing code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine for versions 1.4+, so I don't think you've got a deprecation issue.

As Greg said, you haven't invoked the document ready method. You also haven't invoked the modalTest() function, so the simplemodal $('').modal method won't fire.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   function modalTest() {
     showModal();
     setTimeout(function() {
       hideModal();
     },2000000);
   }

   function showModal() {
     $("#downloadbox").modal({ /* Pass simplemodal config here*/ });
   }

   function hideModal() {
     $.modal.close();
   }   

   modalTest();
 });
```